# Should I get ID the user using websockets or REST in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework, django-channels

I use in my project REST for registration and user authentication. When the user logs in he can send message to backend using websockets. I save his all messages to my database. At the moment in my database I have columns `id` and `message`. I would like to add also id of the user which sends message to backend. My model looks in this way:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

I want to achieve this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Message(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
    message = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

My question is how should I add the user ID to my database with his message. ID of this user should be sended using websockets or for instance header in REST?

consumers.py:

```
def msg_consumer(message):
    text = message.content.get('text')
    Message.objects.create(
        message=text,
    )
    Group("chat").send({'text': text})


def ws_connect(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the chat group
    Group("chat").add(message.reply_channel)

    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            'message': 'Welcome'
        })
    })


def ws_receive(message):

    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

    print("Backend received message: " + message.content['text'])
    Message.objects.create(
        message = message.content['text'],
    )
```

**UPDATE**
At the moment I try in the way shown below but I am not sure whether it is done properly? Additionally I wonder whether it is possible to use one URL for all users? For instance every client uses localhost:8000 but chats are separated and user see only own messages and responses from backend. He doesn't have access to another chats. Besides I have to be sure that the every user id for websockets is the same as user id for REST.

routes.py:

```
route("websocket.connect", ws_connect, path=r"^/(?P<room_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$"),
route("websocket.receive", ws_receive, path=r"^/(?P<room_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$"),
route("websocket.disconnect", ws_disconnect, path=r"^/(?P<room_name>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$"),
```

consumers.py:

```
@channel_session_user_from_http
def ws_connect(message):
    # Accept the connection
    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})
    # Add to the chat group
    Group("chat-%s" % message.user.username[0]).add(message.reply_channel)

    message.reply_channel.send({
        "text": json.dumps({
            'message': 'Welcome'
        })
    })

@channel_session_user
def ws_receive(message):

    message.reply_channel.send({"accept": True})

    print("Backend received message: " + message.content['text'])
    Message.objects.create(
        message = message.content['text'],
    )

    Channel("chat-%s" % message.user.username[0]).send({
        "text": json.dumps({
             'message': 'Can we start?'
         })
    })
@channel_session_user
def ws_disconnect(message):
    Group("chat-%s" % message.user.username[0]).discard(message.reply_channel)
```

Comment: don't you have all the details of the user in the `request` object already? as in `request.user.id`

Comment: If you mean `request` in REST then yes, it is. But when user sends message using websockets he doesn't send it.

Comment: Does my question means `How to get the currently logged in user's user id in Django?` No, I am asking how to authenticate user using both websockets and REST.

Comment: Did you really ask that? :)

Comment: I think so. I am not sure which way I should use to authenticate user using websockets. Because when I use REST I send token in header. With websockets it does not seem so easy. But I don't have much experience with channels.

Comment: Sorry, I can't help. I found [this](https://blog.heroku.com/in_deep_with_django_channels_the_future_of_real_time_apps_in_django) on the web which might help you *handle different channels in django*, but for appropriate answers try changing your tags and include the websocket audience

Comment: i can't understand what exactly do u want to achieve with websockets but in django rest you should use tokenauthentication for  authenticating  the user...

Comment: @amrit I use Token in REST to authenticate users. But I also use websockets to send message to my backend. And I don't know how to check id of the user who sends message. Is it a little clearer know?

Comment: actually if you use use Token in REST to authenticate users then you can provide the token with the request which you send to your backend...and then in  the backend you check for that token against the user to get user details

Comment: @amrit Do you mean to send user token in body of message?

Comment: yes,perhaps but it would be more easy to help if you show the code for how you are sending the message..@JohnSmith

Comment: @amrit I added my `consumers` source code into update question.

Comment: you can use channel_session_user .Go to this link for more detail https://github.com/andrewgodwin/channels-examples/blob/master/multichat/chat/consumers.py

Comment: @amrit Can I use websocket channel for every user using the same URL for everyone or every user has to have own url?